# R dataframe reshaping. Column headers need to become values... dcast no avail

Tags: r, dcast

I am new to R and I am trying to convert a dataframe that is shaped as

```
    actor   <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
    code1 <- c("c1","c2", "c3")
    measure_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
    measure_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)

    x <- data.frame( actor, player ,measure_1, measure_2, measure_3 )

      actor  code1 measure_1 measure_2 
    1    a1     c1         1         4         
    2    a2     c2         2         5         
    3    a3     c3         3         6
```

```
into
```

```
     actor   code1 meausures   value
    1    a1   c1  measure_1     1      
    2    a1   c1  measure_2     4
    3    a2   c2  measure_1     2
    4    a2   c2  measure_2     5
    5    a3   c3  measure_1     3
    6    a3   c3  measure_2     6
```

I tried to use, dcast but to no avail. 
I am not trying to aggregate and use another function to ind mean etc. 
It is just a reordering of the matrix. But the column headers(measure_1 and measure2) 
actually become values in the second form and new column headers are assigned.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: using `reshape2` do `melt(x)`instead of `dcast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)

actor   <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
code1 <- c("c1","c2", "c3")
measure_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
measure_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)

x <- data.frame( actor, code1 ,measure_1, measure_2)

melt(x, id.vars = c("actor", "code1"),
     variable.name = "measures",
     value.name = "value")
```

Comment: Thank you, I had tried melt but it seems I have misunderstood the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a recent version of tidyr, so you might want to update the package before seeing if the solution works for you.

If you're familiar with tidyr check out this vignette
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Its the tidyverse version of reshape2 with respect to reshaping data.

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

actor   <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
code1 <- c("c1","c2", "c3")
measure_1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
measure_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)

x <- tibble( actor, code1 ,measure_1, measure_2)


x %>% 
        pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('measure'), 
                     names_to = 'measure', 
                     values_to = 'value')

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  actor code1 measure   value
  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1 a1    c1    measure_1     1
2 a1    c1    measure_2     4
3 a2    c2    measure_1     2
4 a2    c2    measure_2     5
5 a3    c3    measure_1     3
6 a3    c3    measure_2     6
```